# Log4j not saving into file

Tags: java, log4j

I tried to save my error logs to file using log4j. My code looks like:

Import:

```
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
```

Code:

```
private Logger logger2 = Logger.getLogger(ExceptionSaver.class);
logger2.info("Logger is configured correctly but sth is wrong " + e.getMessage());
```

Config file log4j.properties

```
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, default.out, default.file

# System.out.println appender for all classes
log4j.appender.default.out=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.default.out.threshold=DEBUG
log4j.appender.default.out.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.default.out.layout.ConversionPattern=%-5p %c: %m%n

log4j.appender.default.file=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.default.file.append=true
log4j.appender.default.file.file=/logs/mylogfile.log
log4j.appender.default.file.threshold=INFO
log4j.appender.default.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.default.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%-5p %c: %m%n
```

My code is inside: 
main/java/com/co/sp/el/cl/log

Config is inside:
main/resources

Unfortunately the log is only printed inside console. There is no file created with log. Project is built with gradle, I added dependency

```
compile group: 'log4j', name: 'log4j', version: '1.2.17'
```

Comment: Set `log4j.appender.FILE.ImmediateFlush=true`

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't help.

Comment: Please check the user have sufficient privileges to create the logs/mylogfile.log file

Comment: Yes I am on admin account and I run IntelliJ as admin.

Comment: Are you trying to create log file in the project context or another location ?

Comment: I am trying to save it inside project context.
main/ logs/

Comment: `log4j.appender.R.File=./logs/mylogfile.log` If your logs folder is in same hierarchy of src folder.

Comment: It's still not saving error to the file.

Comment: Is file there ?

Comment: Log4j is not creating any file, I created it on my own but nothing is written to it

Comment: `log4j.appender.FILE.File=${log}/mylogfile.log` Try this way it will create log file under user folder / log4j in your system

Comment: Still, nothing happend.

Comment: Share your project via GitHub if you can. Otherwise, I am helpless.

Comment: It's commercial project, unluckily I can't. I wrote the project structure and code used by logger. I can't do more. But  thank You for all your help.

Comment: I found that there is some exception during compilation. That's the log
https://pastebin.com/FRjaE8bv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it, I changed config to:

```
log4j.rootLogger=debug, stdout, R

log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout

# Pattern to output the caller's file name and line number.
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%5p [%t] (%F:%L) - %m%n

log4j.appender.R=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.R.File=./logs/logError.log

log4j.appender.R.MaxFileSize=100KB
# Keep one backup file
log4j.appender.R.MaxBackupIndex=1

log4j.appender.R.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.R.layout.ConversionPattern=%p %t %c - %m%n
```